# altering variable inside print/echo?

Tags: php

cant you?

Instead of

```
$next_page = $pageNumber + 1;
print '<a href="'.$url.'/page/'.$next_page.'">Next &raquo;</a>';
```

i would like to write it like this

```
print '<a href="'.$url.'/page/'.$pageNumber+1.'">Next &raquo;</a>';
```

the last one gives my parse error. why?

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the operation between brackets:

```
print '<a href="'.$url.'/page/'.($pageNumber+1).'">Next &raquo;</a>';
```

That should do the trick.

To clarify: Right now you are trying to concat a number (1) and a string, PHP can't do that.
If you put the expression between brackets, the result becomes a regular variable for the parser, which can be auto typed to a string and thus used in a concatenation.

Comment: Actually, you're wrong. PHP can concat a number and a string. It can not, however, add two strings, and since concatenation happens before addition, that's what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Because of operator precedence. This will work:

```
print '<a href="'.$url.'/page/'.($pageNumber+1).'">Next &raquo;</a>';
```